# C# LINQ make any take 2 or more from array

Tags: c#, linq

```
var values = new[] { "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "?" };

if (values.Any(s => passwordSec.Contains(s)) && passwordSec.Length > 7)
```

I've been trying to figure out how to make the any method to take 2 or more characters from the array to become true. As of right now it only has to find one in passwordSec(Which is the password string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Any` explicitly means it'll return true if *any* of the items match the supplied predicate. What you want to check is *how many* of the items match the supplied predicate. So, use `Count`.

```
if (values.Count(s => passwordSec.Contains(s)) >= 2 && passwordSec.Length > 7)
```

Alternatively, if you want to check that they use two *different* items of `values`, you could use `Intersect`, which discards duplicates:

```
if (values.Intersect(passwordSec).Count() >= 2 && passwordSec.Length > 7)
```

Answer (score 3):

For short sequences, `Count` will be sufficiently performant (see Rob's answer). However, it will enumerate the entire sequence in order to arrive at the answer. This is sub-optimal in situations when `values` contains thousands of items, of which hundreds could be matching.

For longer sequences when you wish to short-circuit comparisons as soon as `N`-th item is found, you can skip `N-1` item, and then use `Any()` on the result:

```
const int targetCount = 2;
if (values.Where(s => passwordSec.Contains(s)).Skip(targetCount-1).Any() && passwordSec.Length > 7) {
    ...
}
```